# Change routing basing on language, translate URL parts

Tags: php, routes, symfony1, translation, symfony-1.2

Is it posible in Symfony 1.2 to change routing basing on lang?

In my system there are 2 langs - EN, PL

Sample route look like this:

```
produkt_show:
  url:   /products/:pslug/:idslug
  param: { module: product, action: show }
```

What I want to achieve: I want produkt_show route to match [and generate] different url depending on the current language. So in PL my url would look like this:

```
 /produkty/:pslug/:idslug
```

It is essential those routes to have the same names. I can't change all url_for/link_to etc. calls and pass different routes names to them.

If anything is unclear -please, ask ahead.

**UPDATE**

according to the advice of j0k I used plugin. I choosed zxI18nRoutingPlugin. It seems to partialy work - it resolves url to right route if I write it literally in browser address input. But it still generates URLs that are not translated.

e.g.

my route:

```
contact_form:
  url:   /contact_form
  param: { module: contact_request, action: new}
```

trans unit:

```
        <trans-unit>
            <source>contact_form</source>
            <target>formularz-kontaktowy</target>
        </trans-unit>
```

generated url:

```
<a href="/contact_form" title="Kontakt" class="menu-contact"> Kontakt </a>
```

But if I type BASE_URL/formularz-kontaktowy - right action is executed.

This is my configuration from dev toolbar:

```
Request:

    parameterHolder:
      action: new
      module: contact_request
      sf_culture: pl
    attributeHolder:
      sf_route: 'sfRoute Object()'

User

    options:
      auto_shutdown: false
      culture: pl
      default_culture: pl_PL
      use_flash: true
      logging: '1'
      timeout: 10800
    attributeHolder:
      symfony/user/sfUser/attributes: { LAST_CATEGORY_ID_PATH_VAR: null, product_elements_on_page: 50 }
    culture: pl_PL
```

I just can't figure it out, I would appreciate any help, suggestions, anything, because I'm stuck with this.

**UPDATE 2**

factories.yml:

```
all:
  routing:
#    class: sfPatternRouting
#    param:
#      generate_shortest_url:            true
#      extra_parameters_as_query_string: true
    class: zxPatternI18NRouting
    param:
     generate_shortest_url:            true
     extra_parameters_as_query_string: true
     use_cultures:                     [pl, de, en, ru]   # destination cultures. Plugin looks for translations for these cultures.
     culture_into_url:                 false      # defines if culture should be always placed in url
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some plugins that can handle such case (or at least gave you a way to do this on your own):

- [zxI18nRoutingPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/zxI18nRoutingPlugin/1_4_0?tab=plugin_readme)

  > The zxI18nRoutingPlugin extends sfPatternRouting class giving possibility to translate routes patterns static text to different languages.
- [gbI18nRoutePlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/gbI18nRoutePlugin/0_1_0?tab=plugin_readme)

  > Easy way to have I18N Routing.

[An other option](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_2/en/19?orm=Doctrine#chapter_19_culture_in_the_url) can be to add the culture inside the route, like /pl/product, /en/product, etc ..

Comment: That's just sooo cool. Thanks. I knew about the last option before, but it not the solution our customer would like. I'll try to use plugins and write in some time if they worked.

Comment: I used zxI18nRoutingPlugin, and it seems to work partially, but... it still generates URLs that are not transleted. It resolves translated route correlcty if I type it in the address input literally. I'll put an example to my question in a moment.

Comment: How to you generate url? What's the value of `cultures_into_url`? What's the value of `use_cultures` ?

Comment: See my update for my full routing conf. 

`use_cultures: [pl, de, en, ru]` , `cultures_into_url: false`